# Certbot wildcard with express

Tags: node.js, express, ssl-certificate

I created a wildcard for `*.example.com`, but as expected when someone goes to `example.com` the ssl certificate is no longer valid.

Should I have created a `*example.com` wildcard ssl certificate (is that even possible ?), or should I create a seperate `example.com` ssl certificate and serve that somehow on the fly depending on what address has been used ?

My current setup (app is an express app)

```js
http
    .createServer((req, res) => {
        console.log('Redirecting to: ', `https://${req.headers.host}${req.url}`);
        res
            .writeHead(301, {
                Location: `https://${req.headers.host}${req.url}`,
            })
            .end();
    })
    .listen(8081, () => {
        console.log('http upgrade server online on port 8081');
    });

https
    .createServer(
        {
            key: readFileSync(resolve(cwd(), 'cert', 'privkey.pem')),
            cert: readFileSync(resolve(cwd(), 'cert', 'fullchain.pem')),
        },
        app
    )
    .listen(8080, () => {
        console.log('Secure Server is listening on port 8080');
    });
```

I have an a record for my domain (example.com) and a cname for the subdomain www

Comment: Side note: Do not let a node process running directly on the internet. use a reverse proxy to pass requests to your app, like nginx or apache. And to the cert stuff there.

Comment: @bartonjs Yes it did thank you :D

Comment: @Marc Why not though? It's an express server with helmet that serves static files :D

Comment: Because to write a webserver is not easy. There are thousends of things to pay attention for. And the best example given from your self: Express & node is not desigend to "serve static files". Thats exactly what nginx was writen for. to serve static files. Belive me, you dont wont to run your application server directly on the interweebz ;)
Years of experience and security concerns "forbid" such behavior. BUT: You are free to belive and do what ever you want...

Comment: @Marc Instead of saying believe me you could give links / articles / other information to read :) I'll look into that but the way you presented your argument didn't make it sound super credible or worthy of looking into it

Comment: As i sayed, node was not desinged to run directly on the internet. And again: To write a webserver is not easy. There are hundreds of webserver that you can chain in front of your applications server. Why dont you expose a tomact app directly on the internet ? The same reason goes for your node app. Lass mal hier diskutieren: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224869/room-for-marc-and-twiggeh